# Overriding jQuery plugins init function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, overriding

I want to override a init function of a jquery plugin & also a custom function (html, in example) of the plugin. But nothing is working. Here is my code

Thanks in advance.

```js
(function(jQuery) {
  jQuery.mainplugin = function(element, options) {
    var defaults = {};

    this.init = function() {
      this.settings = jQuery.extend({}, defaults, options);
      alert('main')
      // more code here
    };

    this.html = function() {
      // main code here 
    }

    this.init();
  };

  jQuery.fn.mainplugin = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      if (undefined == jQuery(this).data('mainplugin')) {
        var plugin = new jQuery.mainplugin(this, options);
        jQuery(this).data('mainplugin', plugin);
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Here is my code for override:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $.fn.mainplugin.init = function() {
    alert('override')
  }

  $.fn.mainplugin.html = function() {
    alert('override')
  }

  $(".is-wrapper").mainplugin();
});
```

Comment: $(".is-wrapper").mainplugin({ 
          init: function() { //custom function }
      });

like this @RoryMcCrossan ??

Comment: Yes. I added an answer below to give you a complete example.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 'overriding' the functions, pass them in to the plugin via the `options` object:

```js
(function($) {
  $.mainplugin = function(element, options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
      init: null,
      html: null
    }, options);

    this.init = settings.init || function() {
      console.log('main')
    };

    this.html = settings.html || function() {
      console.log('html');
    }

    this.init();
  };

  $.fn.mainplugin = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      if (undefined == $(this).data('mainplugin')) {
        var plugin = new $.mainplugin(this, options);
        $(this).data('mainplugin', plugin);
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function($) {
  // plain
  $('.foo').mainplugin().data('mainplugin').html();

  // overridden
  $(".is-wrapper").mainplugin({
    init: function() {
      console.log('init override');
    },
    html: function() {
      console.log('html override');
    }
  }).data('mainplugin').html();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="is-wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: thanks @Rory, you code works. But my original plugin has code like above in example. I see you modified main plugin code. How can I override without modifying main plugin code ?

Comment: You can use the same pattern your current code does if you'd prefer, although you'd need to access options before extending it, which will be ugly. The method I used above is standard practice as per the [jQuery plugin guide](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).

Comment: but my current code dont work here. Thats why I am asking. I need to make anyhow working. actually, I am not thinking about code standard right now.

$.fn.mainplugin.init = function() {
    alert('override')
  }

Comment: if u could give another example, that would be great help.